# msbuild can't find MSBuild.dll on openSUSE Tumbleweed

Tags: msbuild, mono, monodevelop

I tried running msbuild on openSUSE Tumbleweed and it returns the following error:

```
Cannot open assembly '/usr/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/MSBuild.dll': No such file or directory.
```

Using find I located the dll in this direcory`/usr/lib/mono/Current/bin/MSBuild.dll` so I'm guessing this is a configuration issue in which the executable, or the mono framework, is trying to find the dll in the wrong directory.

Similarly, opening projects in monodevelop throws this error:

```
The type initializer for 'MonoDevelop.Projects.MSBuild.MSBuildEvaluationContext' threw an exception
```

I'm thinking the monodevelop issue is a consequence of the error in msbuild. Any ideas on how I could fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What command gives you the error message? Based on find result, your Mono installation is pretty new (mapping to latest MSBuild on Windows), but MonoDevelop 7.x might not work as it hasn't been updated for a long time.

Comment: Hi Lex Li, I'm running this command: francisco@pc>msbuild

Comment: Then try to use a tool such as Visual Studio Code on Linux (or JetBrains Rider if you like). MonoDevelop is no longer the primary option to use, unless Microsoft revamps it.